# call svg view elements anywhere in the app

Tags: javascript, html, svg

I'm having trouble figuring out how to call icons saved in a single svg image, first of all i would like to understand how coordinates works, i mean how to call a certain icon in a big image to a html element like `<img>`, I read somewhere that there's a way to call the icons by name if you've already setup `<view>` elements like this:

```
<view id="icon-heart-view" viewBox="0 32 32 32" />
<img src="icons.svg#icon-heart-view" alt="Heart">
```

But i don't understand how they are loaded to the page to only call them to a view element? also when having many different views how would i store them all to be able to call any icon anywhere?

I'm building my app under MEAN Stack, if someone knows a trick for this please share.

Answer (score 1):

I think this page will answer a lot of your questions:
https://css-tricks.com/svg-fragment-identifiers-work/

The image is loaded as any image, but when being displayed it will use the named view from inside the SVG-file or a viewBox in the link.

In an image I have 3 view elements

```
<svg
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
    width="252" height="68"
    viewBox="0 0 126 34"
    id="Cannulation"
    version="1.1">

    <view id="buttonhole" viewBox="0 0 126 34" />
    <view id="ropeladder" viewBox="0 35 126 34" />
    <view id="area" viewBox="0 70 126 34" />
<!-- Image contents here -->
</svg>
```

Displaying the image without any arguments, will show the default view from the SVG-element's viewBox

```
<img src="Cannulation.svg"/>
```

To display the third view in this SVG-file I can use either one of these:

```
<!-- View named "area" in svg-file -->
<img src="Cannulation.svg#area"/>
<!-- View created in html, no view necessary in svg-file -->
<img src="Cannulation.svg#svgView(viewBox(0,70,126,34))"/>
```

The same three examples in CSS:

```
body { background: url("Cannulation.svg") }
body { background: url("Cannulation.svg#area") }
body { background: url("Cannulation.svg#svgView(viewBox(0,70,126,34))") }
```

The values of the viewBox are:

```
viewBox( start_x, start_y, width, height )
```

The upper left corner will be (0,0)

**Edit:** Removed links to my testing site, since the links are only temporary

Comment: This should be a comment, and actually from there is from where i took the example

Comment: Somehow it is, but what i really need to know is how could i load the image just once in the app, and then keep using the svg to get the icons...

Comment: I am just guessing here, but in a browser loading a file once will cache it, so fetching it multiple times would hardly make a difference.

Comment: [Here](https://css-tricks.com/using-svg/) is a tip about caching svg, though it is meant for a browser. Check the part about "Using SVG as an <object>"